# Snowflake connector "Cannot connect to Snowflake"

Tags: apache-kafka, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-cloud

I was working with Kafka and try to connect snowflake with it but it's not connecting.
It gives some kind of regional error that the server and cluster should be on the same region, and I tried it on local Kafka and did not accept the "snowflake.url.name".

here is the config file in distributed mode.

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" localhost:8083/connectors/ -d '
{
  "name":"XYZCompanySensorData",
  "config":{
    "connector.class":"com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max":"2",
    "topics":"MysqlJConfluent.source.user_details",
    "buffer.count.records":"10000",
    "buffer.flush.time":"60",
    "buffer.size.bytes":"5000000",
    "snowflake.url.name":"fk79721.europe-west2.gcp.snowflakecomputing.com",
    "snowflake.user.name":"********",
    "snowflake.private.key":"********************************************",
    "snowflake.database.name":"DEMO_DB",
    "snowflake.schema.name":"PUBLIC",
    "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter":"com.snowflake.kafka.connector.records.SnowflakeAvroConverter"
  }
}'
```

Log file :

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Wed, 28 Apr 2021 11:50:41 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 368
Server: Jetty(9.4.33.v20201020)

{"error_code":400,"message":"Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 3 error(s):\nsnowflake.url.name: Cannot connect to Snowflake\nsnowflake.user.name: Cannot connect to Snowflake\nsnowflake.private.key: Cannot connect to Snowflake\nYou can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/connector-plugins/{connectorType}/config/validate`"}
```

Please let me know how can I connect.

Comment: Are you sure the credentials are correct? And that url is accessible from where the connectors run?

Comment: Yes, the credentials are correct. I tested with multiple accounts but no use.

Comment: It's hard to provide much more assistance. Did you try contacting Snowflake support?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
"snowflake.url.name":"fk79721.europe-west2.gcp.snowflakecomputing.com
```

shows that you're not closing the quotes, and it should be like this:

```
"snowflake.url.name":"fk79721.europe-west2.gcp.snowflakecomputing.com:443"
```

Comment: it was a typo error while I was pasting it in the StackOverflow... it was correct and still getting with same error.
the HTTPS:// and port number is optional and I tried with them but still no use.

Comment: Try the [**curl**](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Error-connecting-Kafka-Connector-to-snowflake-DB) mentioned there and see what error you get.